ImportError: cannot import name 'subset_frame' from 'great_tables._tbl_data' while using the python reactable library
I am trying to run this example from the documentation of reactable python library.
I am getting this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'subset_frame' from 'great_tables._tbl_data'

My requirements.txt looks like this:
reactable==0.1.0
polars==1.7.0
great_tables

I am trying to generate an interactive table in python using the reactable library. The example code does not seem to execute despite all the available libraries.

The bug was fixed after the last release in this commit, so the bug will be fixed in next release.
As a work around you can install the package directly from GitHub :
pip install git+https://github.com/machow/reactable-py.git

Update : Resolved in v0.1.1
it was fixed in the new release . you can install it using pip:
pip install reactable


I will try this and get back!

No need for that ! I updated the answer . as it was fixed in v0.1.1

Cool, it is great then!

Yeah! Can you close the question !

Mostly its dependency issue
try this:
pip install --upgrade reactable

then
pip uninstall reactable great_tables polars
pip install reactable great_tables polars


Had tried all above options before I posted here. Thanks.
